# Updating MS Access database record in Lazarus

Tags: ms-access, freepascal, lazarus

I am using Lazarus with MS Access database. Updating the records does not work. Code:

```
  Form1.SQLQuery1.Edit;
  Form1.SQLQuery1.FieldByName('field1').AsString := Edit1.Text;
  Form1.SQLQuery1.FieldByName('field2').AsString := Edit2.Text;
  Form1.SQLQuery1.FieldByName('field3').AsString := Edit3.Text;
  Form1.SQLQuery1.FieldByName('field4').AsString := Edit4.Text;
  Form1.SQLQuery1.Post;
  Form1.SQLQuery1.ApplyUpdates;
```

even adding

```
SQLTransaction1.Commit
```

does not work, changes are not saved to database, especially if the record is the last record.
How is this supposed to be done in Lazarus?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding Update record. Something like this:

```
Form1.SQLQueryMdb.Edit;
Form1.SQLQueryMdb.UpdateRecord;
Form1.SQLQueryMdb.FieldByName('State Name').AsString:= Edit1.Text;
Form1.SQLQueryMdb.Post;
Form1.SQLQueryMdb.ApplyUpdates;
DBGrid1.Refresh;
```